# I made a library of Pusher.com myself, but

Tags: node.js, pusher

In laaS which I currently use, since I can not use library prepared by Pusher.com, API error occurs, so I installed my library by myself. Where is wrong?

This is the node.js code

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const request = require('superagent');
const NCMB = require('ncmb');
module.exports = (req,res)=>{
    const applicationKey = '09exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    const clientKey = '3f3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    saveDataStore(applicationKey, clientKey, req.body).then(()=>{
        console.log('1');
        console.log(req.body);

        return sendPusher('e7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '6xxxxxxx', req.body)
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        res.json({});
    }).catch((err)=>res.status(401).json(err));
}
;

const saveDataStore = (applicationKey,clientKey,body)=>{
    const ncmb = new NCMB(applicationKey,clientKey);
    const Chat = ncmb.DataStore('Chat');
    const chat = new Chat;
    return chat
        .set('chatid', body.chatid)
        .set('touser', body.touser)
        .set('message', body.message)
        .save()
}

const sendPusher = (authKey,secretKey,appId,body)=>{

    const authTimestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
    const authVersion = '1.0';

    const method = 'POST';
    const path = `/apps/${appId}/events`;
    console.log('2');
    console.log(path);
    const message = {
        data: JSON.stringify({
            touser: body.touser,
            message: body.message
        }),
        name: "message",
        channel: body.chatid
    };
    console.log('3');
    const bodyMd5 = crypto
        .createHash('md5')
        .update(JSON.stringify(message))
        .digest('hex');
    const queryString = `auth_key=${authKey}&auth_timestamp=${authTimestamp}&auth_version=${authVersion}&body_md5=${bodyMd5}`;
    const authSigning = [
        method,
        path,
        queryString
    ].join("\n");
    const signature = crypto
        .createHmac("SHA256", secretKey)
        .update(authSigning)
        .digest("hex");
    return request
        .post(`https://api.pusherapp.com${path}?${queryString}&auth_signature=${signature}`)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .send(JSON.stringify(message))
}
```

and this is result

```
{
    "original": null,
    "response": {
        "req": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "https://api.pusherapp.com/apps/618521/events?auth_key=exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&auth_timestamp=1540193698.244&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=79bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&auth_signature=02xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "data": "{\"data\":\"{\\\"touser\\\":\\\"x4Kxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"This is message\\\"}\",\"name\":\"message\",\"channel\":\"Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}",
            "headers": {
                "user-agent": "node-superagent/2.3.0",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        "header": {
            "content-type": "text/html;charset=utf-8",
            "server": "thin",
            "content-length": "17",
            "connection": "Close"
        },
        "status": 400,
        "text": "Unknown auth_key\n"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: It says `Unknown auth_key`, so your auth key is probably not valid.

Comment: The client can connect with　this　auth_key.　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-ap1.pusher.com:443/app/e7xxxxxxxxx?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false"}　　　　　　　　　　　　701SOPusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"XZxxxxxx"}}